# Should I use Transaction as my table name?

Tags: mysql, sql

I my application I created a table with name **Transaction**. Does this name make any conflict with **MySQL transaction**?

Comment: You shouldn't use keywords (even non-reserved keywords) as object identifiers in any language or system - even if it works de-jure, lots of third-party tooling will choke on it. Also, using singular (non-plural) names for tables is a... _somewhat controversial_ practice.

Comment: Why did you tag SQL Server if you are interested in MySQL?

Comment: @DaleK if any one there can help that why i tagged SQL Server .

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are using, they are all quite different, so someone familiar with SQL Server may have no knowledge of MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

`TRANSACTION` is a MySQL keyword, but it is not a *reserved* keyword, meaning that you may use it for a table name without requiring backticks around it.  That being said, I would still recommend that you *not* use `TRANSACTION` to name your tables.  The reason for this is that `TRANSACTION` may appear throughout your code base as a keyword, and you want to avoid any confusion which might arise for anyone in the future who inherits your code.

For a workaround name, assuming you were selling books, you could use the name `book_transactions`.

Comment: In my databases where I have a table that stores business-domain _transactions_ I use the name `Txns` - not just because it isn't a keyword, but because it's very succinct without being cryptic :)

Comment: @Dai Curiously, I store details about Jamie Foxx, Woody Harrelson, and Tommy Lee Jones in a table of the same name, and for the same reason.

Comment: All good stuff here. Unfortunately, your comment on an earlier question sent me in to apoplexy (something about swapping syntax), but maybe, when I've calmed down again. :-) Happy new year

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, that question also irked me, and the weird thing is, if that person just copied the code from a tutorial, doesn't that imply that the tutorial were itself incorrect?  I really don't know ...

Comment: @Strawberry can u please help on this

Comment: I think TB's got it covered

Answer (score 0):

In general, you want to avoid conflicts with SQL keywords -- even if they are not reserved.  For one thing, they could become reserved in the future.

In general, I use the following naming convention:

- Tables in the plural:  `transactions`.
- Ids in the singular with `id` appended:  `transactionId` or `transaction_id`.
- Avoid conflict with all reserved words and keywords and no special characters in the names.

The pluralization rule is because a table contains multiple copies of an entity.  It also conveniently avoids most reserved words and keywords -- `VALUES` being a notable exception.